# Removing application title and changing taskbar icon

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to remove the application title from the title bar while still keeping it in the task bar.

I tried using `SetWindowText(_T(""));` on dialog initialization. It removed the text from the task bar button as well.

I would also like to know if there is a way to make the application icon that is showing in the taskbar different from the one that is in the title bar a.k.a system menu icon.

Is there any decent way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Cody Gray's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628211/419776

WPF, but the same goes for MFC.

Comment: Actually I've found an easier way of doing it by handling the WM_GetIcon message and giving different values for ICON_BIG, ICON_SMALL and ICON_SMALL2...

Works perfectly.... But thanks for your answer I really appreciated it.

Comment: Interesting. Were you able to get the desired behavior using that technique?

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to achive this is by handling the Wm_GetIcon message and then setting the big and two small icons individually by assigning ICON_BIG, ICON_SMALL and ICON_SMALL2 each a different value.

As for the text, it check the answer above.